# Trying to use Boost with CMake in CLion

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake, gmp

I'm new in C++ and met a problem didn't find a solution in internet.

I have Mac OS Catalina on board, bundled CMake, Boost and gmp installed with brew.

So trying to use Boost, specifically multiprecision lib for estimating big Fibonacci numbers. Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main() {
    unsigned int start = clock();

    mpz_int numFirst = 0;
    mpz_int numSecond = 1;

    mpz_int numNext = 0;

    int n;
    std::cout << "n = ";
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        numNext = numFirst + numSecond;
        numFirst = numSecond;
        numSecond = numNext;
    }

    std::cout << n << " Fib's number: " << numNext << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Working time: " << clock() - start;


    return 0;
}
```

I filled CMakeLists.txt with a CLion's template by pressing command+J:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(testing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(testing main.cpp)

# Note: a target should be already defined using 'add_executable' or 'add_library'
target_link_libraries(testing ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Compiling program have an error:

```
In file included from /Users/joelcolbeck/CLionProjects/testing/main.cpp:3:
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.72.0_3/include/boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp:31:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
```

So I tried to include gmp in CMakeLists.txt by writing a full path to include directory:

```
...
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.2.0/include)

add_executable(testing main.cpp)

# Note: a target should be already defined using 'add_executable' or 'add_library'
target_link_libraries(testing ${Boost_LIBRARIES} /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.2.0/lib)
```

And then, when compiling program, have linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___gmp_get_memory_functions", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::str(long, unsigned int) const in main.cpp.o
  "___gmpz_add", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::eval_add(boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int&, boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int const&, boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int const&) in main.cpp.o
  "___gmpz_clear", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::~gmp_int() in main.cpp.o
  "___gmpz_get_str", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::str(long, unsigned int) const in main.cpp.o
  "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::operator=(long) in main.cpp.o
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::gmp_int() in main.cpp.o
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::operator=(boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int const&) in main.cpp.o
  "___gmpz_set", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::operator=(boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int const&) in main.cpp.o
  "___gmpz_set_si", referenced from:
      boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_int::operator=(long) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [testing] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/testing.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testing.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [testing] Error 2
```

Don't know, what to do with that. I watched some videos about how linker works, but there wasn't any problems like that

Comment: `target_link_libraries` specifies the actual *libraries* to link with, not the directories where they might be located.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, thank you! I added ```libgmp.a``` to path, and it works!

Comment: Note that GMP provides a function to compute a fibonacci number efficiently.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, thanks, will check :)

Comment: @squareskittles Oh, it seems to be. Didn't find it when was looking for an answer. I read many another questions with the same error, but theirs solutions didn't help me. Thank you